# Cyclical counting quantifiers

Tags: logic

In counting logic, how does one assign a meaning to statements such as "There exists $x$ $y$'s such that there exist $y$ $x$'s such that $x>y$. My mind hurts as I try to imagine how to evaluate such a circular statement. I know this is somewhat of an obscure topic, but anyone who does know this, please tell me what statements with cyclical counting quantifiers mean.

Comment: Are such expressions considered well-formed formulas to begin with? (I'd expect that the inductive definition of wff in this context looks like "$\forall x\varphi(x)$" is well formed if $\varphi$ is well-formed and $x$ does not occur bound in $\varphi$," which would rule out this sort of circularity.)